# I am having an issue with Selenium code

Tags: selenium

When I run this script then an error message is occur.

> Element info: {Using=xpath,
>   value=html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/div[1]/fieldset/div/div[17]}

I try this below mentioned code, but it didn't work for me.

```
fd.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/div[1]/fieldset/div/div[17]")).click();
```

Here is the developer code.

```html
<div id="ui-id-5" class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons ui-state-hover" role="tab" aria-controls="ui-id-6" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
<span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"/>
Education Institution
</div>
```

Comment: ...what? Please give a correctly formatted [mcve]. Your question is currently indecipherable.

Comment: Can you please provide some more information as: 1. What is your objective? 2. What are you trying to do? 3. What have you done still now? Show code. 4. What worked for you? 5. Where are you stuck? 6. Update the question with relevant HTML DOM.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I am trying to select a menu tab using xpath. for your reference please visit 117.247.65.9/wb_isgp_test site. Click>GIS Map, Select 4th radio button i.e GP. Click into Whizmap button. Select the Education Institution. Select the element using xpath but all the time an error message is occur. I am unable to run the script using xpath. Code-fd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ui-id-5'])")).click();

Comment: Here is the developer code-                                                                                <div id="ui-id-5" class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons ui-state-hover" role="tab" aria-controls="ui-id-6" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1">
<span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"/>
Education Institution
</div>

Answer (score 0):

A good element locator:

1. is as small as possible to indicate the GUI element
2. will continue working when GUI elements around the GUI element change
3. will continue working when properties of the GUI element change

Not a selenium code issue, Issue with locator you defined. Try this code

```
fd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ui-id-5']")).click();
```

Follow [this](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/best-practices-of-choosing-good-locators-for-your-test-automation-scripts/) for what is a ‘good’ element locator.

Comment: your code does not work due to your `class` attribute is wrong here. Check `html` for more details.

Comment: I got this. Thanks, Nice catch. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code:

```
driver.get("http://117.247.65.9/wb_isgp_test/secured/home.jsp");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElement(By.id("mapUp")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='gp1']"))));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='gp1']")).click();

Thread.sleep(5000);

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Whizmap']")).click();
Thread.sleep(8000);

String childWindow = (String) driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[1];   
driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);  

System.out.println("Switch to new tab.");       
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ui-id-5']")).getText();
System.out.println(text);

WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25);
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ui-id-5']"))));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ui-id-5']")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot@ Jainish Kapadia.Now code working correctly.  Thanks for  answer.                                                                                                             Accepted